# Javascript link in aspx page within a SharePoint frame replaces apostrophes to #39 element

Tags: javascript, encoding, sharepoint-2010, hyperlink, apostrophe

I have problem with SharePoint encoding the javascript link, that normally renders like href="javascript:Function('url');" but in Sharepoint like href="javascript:Function(& #39;url& #39;)" wich of course does not work.

What do I need to do?

I need to be able to use my user control as stand alone as well as linked into a sharepoint page, right!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you inserting the code?  Within a web part, a custom control, etc?

If you are trying to use the Content Editor web part I did notice some differences with it in 2010.  When trying to use items that require javascript I just created a .txt file that resides in the SiteAssets.  The file contains all the HTML/JS that I would normally add to the web part.  Then point/link the Content Editor web part at that file.

This seemed to fix some issues I was having.  Could work for you.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! I had some change of requirements wich allowed me to open the page in a new window. I will keep your solution in mind next time... :)